# Examine significance of the effect of an attribute on the effect of another attribute

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, fishers-exact-test

I'd like to examine the effect of an attribute on the effect of another attribute on certain behaviour. To explain what I mean:

I tested two groups of 110 people on whether they did x. One of the groups had the attribute A, the other did not have A:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|                     |       did x      |     didn't do x  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|     group 0         |         1        |      109         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|     group A         |         8        |      102         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I also tested x with two more groups, both of which have another attribute B, which is independent from attribute A. Again, one group had A, the other did not.

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|                     |       did x      |     didn't do x  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|     group B         |         7        |      103         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|     group BA        |         2        |      108         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

When the subjects had the attribute B, attribute A appears to have a different (opposite) effect on whether subjects did x. I would like to test whether this difference in the effect is statistically significant. Which test could I use to do that?

In case it's relevant: The significance of each table alone is determined with Fisher's exact test (first is significant with p < 0.05, second is not). Doing x and not doing x is mutually exclusive.

I am new to statistics, simple terms and explanations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most general approach, what you want to do is combine the data into one model.  You can think of these data as having a dependent variable (Did / Didn't) and a couple of independent variables (0/B and A/not-A). You could model these data with logistic regression.  The question you are asking is if there is an interaction between 0/B and A/not-A.

There are traditional tests for this question for 2 x 2 x *k* tables.  Namely, the Woolf test and Breslow-Day test.

Because you have low counts in some cells (e.g. 1, 2), these approaches might be deficient.

The following example uses R.  It could be run at [rdrr.io/snippets](http://rdrr.io/snippets).

To summarize the results here, as you suspected, there is a significant interaction of the effect of (A/not-A) with (0/B) (from Woolf test, Breslow-Day test, or the interaction *p* in the `Anova` results). (You'll note that the results of the Woolf test agree precisely with those from the Wald test of the interaction in the `Anova` table.)

```
### Install packages and read data

if(!require(vcd)){install.packages("vcd")}
if(!require(DescTools)){install.packages("DescTools")}
if(!require(car)){install.packages("car")}
if(!require(emmeans)){install.packages("emmeans")}
if(!require(ggplot2)){install.packages("ggplot2")}

Data = read.table(header=T, text="
Group1 Group2     X      Count  
0      not-A      Did      1
0      not-A      Didnt  109 
0      A          Did      8
0      A          Didnt  102

B      not-A      Did      7
B      not-A      Didnt  103 
B      A          Did      2
B      A          Didnt  108
")

Data$X      = factor(Data$X, levels = c("Didnt", "Did"))
Data$Group2 = factor(Data$Group2, levels = c("not-A", "A"))

### Woolf test and Breslow-Day test

Table = xtabs(Count ~  Group2 + X + Group1, data=Data)

library(vcd)

woolf_test(Table)

   ### Woolf-test on Homogeneity of Odds Ratios (no 3-Way assoc.)
   ### 
   ### X-squared = 6.5759, df = 1, p-value = 0.01034

library(DescTools)

BreslowDayTest(Table)

   ### Breslow-Day test on Homogeneity of Odds Ratios
   ### 
   ### X-squared = 8.4376, df = 1, p-value = 0.003675

### Model logistic regession and analysis of deviance table

model = glm(X ~ Group1*Group2, weights=Count, data=Data, family=binomial())

library(car)

Anova(model, test="Wald")

   ### Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)
   ### 
   ###               Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)  
   ### Group1         1 0.1109    0.73908  
   ### Group2         1 0.0033    0.95417  
   ### Group1:Group2  1 6.5759    0.01034 *

### Produce estimates of probabilities and plot

library(emmeans)

marginal = emmeans(model, ~ Group1:Group2, type="response")

marginal

   ### Group1 Group2    prob      SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
   ### 0      not-A  0.00909 0.00905 Inf   0.00128    0.0617
   ### B      not-A  0.06364 0.02327 Inf   0.03064    0.1275
   ### 0      A      0.07273 0.02476 Inf   0.03679    0.1387
   ### B      A      0.01818 0.01274 Inf   0.00455    0.0698
   ### 
   ### Confidence level used: 0.95 
   ### Intervals are back-transformed from the logit scale 

library(ggplot2)

pd = position_dodge(.2)

ggplot(as.data.frame(marginal),
       aes(x     = Group1,
           y     = prob,
           color = Group2)) +

    geom_point(shape = 15,
               size  = 4,
             position = pd) +

    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin  = asymp.LCL,
                      ymax  = asymp.UCL),
                      width = 0.2,
                      size  = 0.7,
                      position = pd) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +

    ylab("Probability of Did")
```

[image: Interaction plot]